# jQuery slow to remove or move div content until page is loaded

Tags: jquery

Notice the link how the content is really slow to hide?
The two top boxes are supposed to hide if the page is set to blog. They do hide but you see them first. Any way to fix this?

Here is my code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.10.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<? if($_GET[p]=="blog")
{{?>    


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#iBox").hide();
$("#Banner").hide();
TweenMax.to($("#Content"), 0, {css:{ y:-360, opacity:1}, ease:Expo.easeInOut, delay:0});
TweenMax.to($("#Bar"), 0, {css:{ y:-360, opacity:1}, ease:Expo.easeInOut, delay:0});

});

</script>

<? }} ?>
```

Comment: You could try reversing it, i.e., hide them with CSS by default and show them with JS when needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CSS**

```
#iBox,#Banner { display:none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You've wrapped your hiding logic in a document.ready(), which is going to wait until every single thing and resource on the page is loaded.  You might consider a script block right after the elements and no document.ready() statement.  Otherwise, hiding them by default is a good idea also as nnnnnnnnnnnn has suggested.